# Unit Test Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Estoy realizando pruebas unitarias por primera vez en Spring Boot. Resulta que me muestra un Error:

```
Field cardRepository in ec.com.alquimiasoft.futgolazoback.service.CardService required a bean of type 'ec.com.alquimiasoft.futgolazoback.repository.CardRepository' that could not be found.
```

Dentro de mi clase de pruebas del controlador tengo solo estas referencias:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@MockBean
private PrognosticService prognosticService;
```

Y dentro de la clase de servicio solo estas

```
@Autowired
private PrognosticRepository prognosticRepository;
```

Mi duda es relacionada conque pueda existir alguna configuracón que sea la que este comprobando en otro servicio que no estoy usando desde la clase de pruebas. En pocas palabras, que si estoy corriendo una unidad de pruebas, porque podría estar sucediendo que lance errores relacionados a otros componentes dentro de la aplicación que son ajenos a la prueba que estoy corriendo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu puedes usar [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito)

```
// Crea un mock de PrognosticRepository para el testeo.
@Mock
private PrognosticRepository prognosticRepository;

// Probando la instancia, mockea **prognosticRepository** deberia injectar mocks. 
@InjectMocks
@Resource
private PrognosticService prognosticService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Inicializa los mocks creados
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // cambia el comportamiento de  `prognosticRepository`
    when(prognosticRepository.save("Valor")).thenReturn("Valor");   
}
```